# How to remove Chapter X with X in report

Tags: chapters

I am aware that this issue has already been discussed in other questions, but I couldn't get my problem solved.

I am using documentclass `report` along with `fullpage` package. How do I replace the Chapter X with just X while maintaining the same font size and margins(as that of the fullpage package)?

Comment: How is fullpage influencing the appearance of the chapter title? Can you give a code example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the chapter head in report is set by

```
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{50\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
        \huge\bfseries \@chapapp\space \thechapter
        \par\nobreak
        \vskip 20\p@
    \fi
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 40\p@
  }}
```

so just redefine without the **Chapter** part:

```
\makeatletter
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{50\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
        \huge\bfseries 
%%%%%%%%\@chapapp\
        \thechapter
        \par\nobreak
        \vskip 20\p@
    \fi
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 40\p@
  }}
\makeatother
```

Comment: How do I access this code block? I don't understand where am I supposed to look for these lines. I am writing my report on overleaf.com. Thanks!!

Comment: Put it in the preamble of your document.

Comment: @MaxFrost ignore the first block, that was just for information, put the second block in your preamble and it will redefine chapter heading layout.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Got it! Thanks a lot! Btw, is it possible to increase the fontsize of the chapter number by making tweaks in your code? I don't find any .pt parameter to control the size.

Comment: @MaxFrost it is `\huge` in the above, you could make it `\Huge` for example.